# iOS: Include the resource(audio) files into the application folder of the app rather than adding into the bundle

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, filesystems, xcode11

Currently my resource(audio) files is included in the bundle. Due to this user is unable to delete the unwanted audio files to save the disk space on his phone. Please let me know how can I directly include the audio files into the Applications folder of app while submitting the build to AppStore and not in the bundle. Thereby user can delete the files which are not of his interest and re-download from the cloud backup hosted on S3 if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish this is to ***NOT*** have the audio files included in the initial app install.

Instead, your app could download the audio files from a hosting service... either download them all on first launch, or download each file as-needed.

You would then store the files on the device so they don't need to be downloaded again... and you could provide a UI to delete files the user no longer wants stored locally.